# How to restructure a loop in order to reduce the objects stored in R environment (Free up Memory)

Tags: r, for-loop, memory-management, out-of-memory, nested-loops

The following code produces a data set (DF5) which consists of 11.88 Billion rows and 5 columns. Evidently, each preceding data set (i.e. especially DF3 and DF4) are huge (datalist3 is nearly 4.4 GB). So, I often face the error "**error: cannot allocate vector of size 906.4 mb**". While doing so all resultant data frames i.e. DF1, DF2,DF3, DF4, and DF5 are stored in environment; however, I only need to store DF5 the final data frame. How do I restructure this code that would enable me to reduce the number of objects stored in environment. I am presuming that this might help in reducing the chances of getting this error. I have already increased by memory limit by passing `memory.limit(size = 10000000000)`

Is there any other way of handling this issue?

I have a 64-bit operating system with a RAM size of 16 GB

**Code**

```
v1 <- seq(0, 1, 0.125)
v3 <- seq(0, 1, 0.1)
v4 <- seq(0.1, 50, 0.5)
v5 <- seq(1, 100, 1)
datalist1 <- vector('list', length(v1))
datalist2 = list()
datalist3 <- vector('list', length(v3))
datalist4 <- vector('list', length(v4))
datalist5 <- vector('list', length(v5))
for (p in seq_along(v5)){
  for (s in seq_along(v4)){
    for (b in seq_along(v3)){
      for(j in seq_along(v1)){
        DF1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(5,60,5), function(i) data.frame(iterator = i, value = rlnorm(n=1000, log(i^2 / sqrt((i*v1[j])^2 + i^2)), sqrt(log(1 + ((i*v1[j])^2 / i^2)))))))
        DF1$CV <- v1[j]
        DF1$beta <- v3[j]
        DF1$spacing=v4[j]
        DF1$p=v5[j]
        datalist1[[j]] <- DF1
      }
      DF2 = do.call(rbind, datalist1)
      datalist2[[b]] <- DF2
    }
    DF3 = do.call(rbind, datalist2)
    datalist3[[s]] <- DF3
  }
  DF4 = do.call(rbind, datalist3) 
  datalist4[[p]] <- DF4
}
DF5 = do.call(rbind, datalist4)
```

Comment: Did you try setting the variables to `NULL` after you use them? Something like `DF4 = NULL` after you insert it into the list.

Comment: Or alternatively, removing the variable from the environment using `rm()`.